# Uncaught referenceError : Angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I am seeing the error as shown in the image. 
[Error displayed in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSa0S.png)

This is my App.js code:

```
 var app = angular.module('PopupDemo',[]);
 app.controller('PopupDemoCont',function($scope) {
 });
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>SignUp</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/App.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="PopupDemo">

    <div data-toggle="validator" class="container-fluid" ng-controller="PopupDemoCont">
        <h1><b>Sign Up</b></h1>
        </br>
        <form id="form" name="userForm" action="Registration.html">
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone fix this?

Comment: You have the app loading before angular. Switch them around.

Comment: @SakethGangam While marking answer, see who answered first :(

Comment: I am really sorry! I am totally new to this! How  can I do it now?

Comment: Read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work @SakethGangam

Comment: I can't see a tick mark beside your answer :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app.js shoud be below angular reference

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/App.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your references Order should be

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/App.js"></script>
```

Comment: why did you remove the answer